# Wordpress AJAX with raw javascript? NO Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Alright, so I have a *related-posts.php* script I wrote and I wish to insert it into posts only upon certain user action (scrolling). I also have a script file which is enqueued by wordpress and loads in footer - in there I've written ajax like so:

```
var  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("relatedPosts").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions/widgets/ajaxa.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

AJAX loads the file, however the problem is: the php script seems to be 'unaware' of the page it loads in since

```
global $post; 
print_r($post);
```

outputs 0 (zero)...

I understand there's a proper way of using ajax in wordpress however all the documentation I found relies heavily on Jquery (which I don't know nor wish to learn at the moment)

How can I make it work using javascript solely?

Comment: As you're already aware this isn't being done the WordPress way. You never tell the PHP file you send the request to what page you're on. The `$post` global is setup by WordPress, are you loading WP inside your PHP file? If not then none of your WP functions are going to work. Just send your request to `admin-ajax.php`, use POST instead of GET if possible, and pass in the post ID.

Comment: You aren't even sending any parameters

Comment: I can't pass post ID - that's why I use "global $post" for... I don't understand how could I send the request to wp-admin? do you mean I should switch the xmlhttp.open url with wp-admin.php url? then who would I retrieve my ajaxa.php file?? 
I need a more thorough answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is unaware of the global $post object because it is not compiled with the rest of the page - you need to think of these as two separate pages that do not share objects in PHP unless they are saved in the session since they are compiled independently.

If you want to find related posts, you should pass the id of the main post to the PHP script generating the associations, then use that to look up the related items within ajax.php... e.g.

```
var  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
     document.getElementById("relatedPosts").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","...mypath.../ajaxa.php?getAssociationsFor=<?php get_the_ID(); ?>",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Then in ajaxa.php something like...

```
htmlspecialchars($_GET["getAssociationsFor"])
```

to get the value passed from the HTML page.

Comment: <?php get_the_ID(); ?> is parsed as text, how do I make it parse correctly?

Comment: it might be just <? ... ?> - use the same opening/closing for your PHP as the other wordpress files. For testing you can hard-code a number that you know exists `?getAssociationsFor=1`. For reference, the get_the_ID() is a wordpress method that MIGHT work for you depending on how you use it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm already familiar with get_the_ID() and many more wordpress built-in functions, I've read through their documentation numerous times now, the <?php along with the entire url are wrapped with quotes " so they are parsed as text I can't escape them...

Comment: I assumed that your javascript was in some .php file but based on your comment I'm guessing that isn't the case. Can you confirm that the JavaScript is or is not in a .php file? (this will ensure that the code within <?...?> is evaluated on the server before the output is sent to the browser.

Comment: yes, my javascript is on a js file which is enqueued using wp_enqueue_script. does that mean I must have it inside a php file?

Comment: Yes, can you try moving that code to a php file and retest? (the right final location will be something to sort out based on your application architecture, but this should get you to the next step)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't works either. inside a php file when I use <?php ?> I get nothing when echoing htmlspecialchars($_GET["getAssociationsFor"]);
when using <? ?> I get  <? get_the_ID(); ?>

Comment: that will have to be on a php page served with a URL that looks like: `myphpfile.php?getAssociationsFor=myId` - this should echo `myId`